# (taylor series) what do i need to do next?

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

[image]

i got the Taylor series of $\sin x/x$ but i don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Pick an "order" for the Taylor series expansion.  Integrate the Taylor series expansion, neglecting the remainder term in the Taylor series expansion.  By analyzing the remainder term in the Taylor series expansion, determine a bound on the error in your integral estimate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a summation sign in your final series.  You can put the series into the integrand and (by assuming absolute convergence) change the order of the integral and the summation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_1^2 \frac{ (-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} \; dx.$$

You can integrate this, evaluate at the endpoints and then you have a nice series answer.  The series is alternating, so it will be easy to bound your error.